# Java - Read Illustrator file IPTC metadata

Tags: java, metadata, adobe-illustrator, iptc

```
Path file = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());
System.out.println("isDirectory: " + attr.isDirectory());
System.out.println("isOther: " + attr.isOther());
System.out.println("isRegularFile: " + attr.isRegularFile());
System.out.println("isSymbolicLink: " + attr.isSymbolicLink());
System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());
```

Above code used to read file metadata. I've tried using JPEG and AI file. How do I do to extract more metadata fields. For an example like image below.
[image: Metadata image]. How do I extract IPTC value like screen shot. Any advice or reference link is highly appreciated. Need to fetch **Headline:, Description:, Keywords:, Title:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the request with using [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/).